# Is it mandatory to change the dtype='object' to 'category' before label encoding

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.x

I have seen some people change the datatype(from object to category) of the feature they want to encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the approach you take for label encoding. If you want to use .cat.codes then you need to convert it into category datatype.

You can also use sklearn [labelencoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) which does this inherently bcoz it can be used to transform non-numerical labels (as long as they are hashable and comparable) to numerical labels.

Comment: Thank you! @ prashant0598

Comment: If this answer helped you pls accept or upvote the answer respectively :)